# how to remove extra space from edit text if Editext hint in 3-4 lines and i have to enter text in single line?

Tags: android

I have to remove extra space from edit Field my hint size is 4 lines and some cases i have to enter only single line text in that case it takes 4 line space i have to remove extra space.

what i can do?

Please provide any solution for that.

Comment: Provide some code on what you have tried?

Comment: It will be good if you provide code or any link

Comment: Please share your xml and java code.

Comment: share xml code and image would be good showing where is extra space for better understanding your problem

Comment: so when you start enter text in edittext you want it to become single line edittext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use **[addTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))**

> Adds a TextWatcher to the list of those whose methods are called whenever this EditText's text changes.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().equals("")) {
                    editText.setHint(getString(R.string.your_hint));
                } else {
                    editText.setHint("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: it's working fine for single edit text. But i have multiple edit text if i take listener for every single edit text than code length is more. so i have implement TextWatcher  and pass this for every edittext but now i am not able to define which edit text  i have set null or which not. orveride methods have  no any view for define

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the solution  **

> This is my XML code

```
`<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/your_hint_text"
    />` 
>
```

**Here is the java file code**

```
final EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().equals("")) {

     editText.setHint(getString(R.string.your_hint_text));
            } else {
                    editText.setHint("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TextWatcher which will respond to the edit Text  text change listener

```
editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(count>0){
                editText.setMaxLines(1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```